# Communicate relation between two table

Tags: qgis, select, relationship-class, relates

At this time, I'm able to create a relation (1:M) between two table or geometries. After, I user Identify tool to exploit the relation. It is only possible to use this feature when your Identify tool is done on one (1) geometry.

Here my question:
Is it possible to select multiple geometries in parent table (select by attribute or location) and communicate to the child table the same selection based on their common attribute (pk,fk).

QGIS 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer using selection (not relation) has been published for this question. [Question on gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119153/querying-related-tables-in-qgis/160289#160289)